# Force next content to come BELOW a variable height DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a CSS-driven tab control that works fine, each page has a different height.

Currently, the next control comes beside the tab control, and I need it to locate BELOW it, considering the variable height of the tab content I'm selecting.  I also need not to fix page height and use scroll bars approach.

Appreciate any help.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div class="tab-control">
        <ul id="navlist" class="tabs">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-1" checked="checked" />
                <label for="tab-1">First Tab</label>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    Content of Tab 1.
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-2" />
                <label for="tab-2">Second Tab</label>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    Line 1 - Tab 2.<br />
                    Line 2 - Tab 2.<br />
                    Line 3 - Tab 2.<br />
                    Line 4 - Tab 2.<br />
                    Line 5 - Tab 2.<br />
                    Line 6 - Tab 2.<br />
                    Line 7 - Tab 2.<br />
                    Line 8 - Tab 2.<br />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-3" />
                <label for="tab-3">Third Tab</label>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    Content of Tab 3.
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        This should come below the tab control.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tab-control {
    clear:both;
    width:700px;
    background-color:#0ff;
}

.tabs {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}

.tabs li {
    float: left;
}

.tabs li > input {
    display: none;
}

.tabs li > label {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #02606d;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height:10px;
    line-height:10px;
    border-right-width:0px;
    border-bottom-width:0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.tabs li:last-child > label {
    border-right-width:1px;
}

.tabs .tab-content {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    padding:5px;
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}



.tabs li > input:checked + label {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.tabs li > input:checked  ~  .tab-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You better take help of Js

Comment: Would you provide how to implement this in my case?

Comment: do u want to make a tab control side by side? and the contents of the element will come under the tab control? on click?

Comment: Can we change the html structure slightly?

Comment: @Abdur Rahim
Yes I want it a horizontal tab buttons (side by side) and the content comes below.  When a tab button is clicked, the content will expand, and the rest of page content (below the tab area) will also shift down or up according the height of the tab page selected.

Comment: @woestijnrog:  Sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on it. I've restructured the html: `input`, `label` and `.tab-content` are siblings of each other. You also need to add the relevant tab-id to the class of the div that holds the contents.

```css
 input {
        display: none;
    }
    .tab-content {
        display: none;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    input:checked + label {
        background: #ccc;  /* We can target the activated tab label */
    }
    /* display only the relevant tab-content */
    input[id=tab-1]:checked ~ div[class~=tab-1],
    input[id=tab-2]:checked ~ div[class~=tab-2],
    input[id=tab-3]:checked ~ div[class~=tab-3]{
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="tab-control">
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-1" checked="checked" />
        <label for="tab-1">First Tab</label>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-2" />
        <label for="tab-2">Second Tab</label>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-3" />
        <label for="tab-3">Third Tab</label>
        <div class="tab-content tab-1"> <!-- Note the tab-1 in the class -->
            Content of Tab 1.
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content tab-2"> <!-- Note the tab-2 in the class -->
            Line 1 - Tab 2.<br />
            Line 2 - Tab 2.<br />
            Line 3 - Tab 2.<br />
            Line 4 - Tab 2.<br />
            Line 5 - Tab 2.<br />
            Line 6 - Tab 2.<br />
            Line 7 - Tab 2.<br />
            Line 8 - Tab 2.<br />
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content tab-3"> <!-- Note the tab-3 in the class -->
            Content of Tab 3.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        This should come below the tab control.
    </div>
```

Comment: Perfect woestijnrog... This looks pretty close to what I need.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
HTML Code:

```
<div class="below-Tab">
        This should come below the tab control.
</div>
```

CSS code

```
 .below-Tab{
      border:1px solid black;
      position:absolute;
      top:200px;
      width:400px;
    }
```

If that's not compatible with your expectations , please explain what exactly do you need , thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Nasco for reply.  In fact this solution fixes height, while the tab control is variable-height.  If the content exceeds 200px height it will interfere with the next content.

Comment: There's an option that you can make your tabs with fixed height and then add overflow:scroll (it will make your tab content scroll able) , and let this div stay like this.. that's an option, another option is to do it with JS.

Comment: Nasco,  Second approach is more suitable, but do we implement it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
         ul li{
             display:inline; //new change for horizontal tab
         }

        .tabs li > label {
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #02606d;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            height: 10px;
            line-height: 10px;
            border-right-width: 0px;
            border-bottom-width: 0px;
            border-top-left-radius: 7px;
            border-top-right-radius: 7px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .tabs li:last-child > label {
            border-right-width: 1px;
        }

        .tabs .tab-content {
            display: none;
            position: relative; /*changes - absolute -> relative*/
            left: 0;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        .below { /* changes - new */
            display:normal;
            position:relative; /* relative*/
            padding-top:20px;  /* for some space above*/
        }


        .tabs li > input:checked + label {
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        .tabs li > input:checked ~ .tab-content {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>   
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="tab-control">
            <ul id="navlist" class="tabs">
                <li >
                    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-1" checked="checked" />
                    <label for="tab-1">First Tab</label>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        Content of Tab 1.
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-2" />
                    <label for="tab-2">Second Tab</label>
                    <div class="tab-content" >
                        Line 1 - Tab 2.<br />
                        Line 2 - Tab 2.<br />
                        Line 3 - Tab 2.<br />
                        Line 4 - Tab 2.<br />
                        Line 5 - Tab 2.<br />
                        Line 6 - Tab 2.<br />
                        Line 7 - Tab 2.<br />
                        Line 8 - Tab 2.<br />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-3"/>
                    <label for="tab-3">Third Tab</label>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        Content of Tab 3.
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="below"> /* added a class .below */
            This should come below the tab control.
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**Please copy the code and paste as a html file and test, that if it is what you wanted.**

Here, I gave the taqb content position as relative and add a class in the div which have to be shown below. and the posiotion of the div is also relative.

Comment: Thanks Abdur Rahim, but this appears to be a vertical tab style. I need a horizontal tab buttons with content below.

Comment: i have added 2 lines of  code to display them horizontal (display: inline;). you are welcome.